# Write External Storage on Android 4.4 and above

Tags: android, permissions, android-4.4-kitkat, android-external-storage

I am trying to write the external storage but I always get the Access denied message.

I set the correct permissions on the manbifest and also I request the write_external_storage permissions at runtime and I am able to write the primary external sdcard:
in my case

`/sdcard (/storage/emulated/0/)`

but I cannot write on the secondary external SD (microsd card) :
in my case

`/storage/C0B9-3B8B/`

I can write the secondary memory only using the path

`/storage/C0B9-3B8B/Android/data/com.example.myapplication/files/`

Is there any way to write a different folder, for example 
`"/storage/C0B9-3B8B/Download"` without rooting the device?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my issue, I need to use the SAF (Storage access framework) as Google describes [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)